# OpenStack Keystone port 5000 used by Python

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone

I'm following official OpenStack documentation to build my first environment and got stuck in configuring Keystone (last step from http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/keystone-install.html)

While trying to restart apache I get error message about port 5000 being used

```
 * Restarting web server apache2
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:5000
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:5000
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Netstat says the port is used by Python and further investigation shows it's somehow related to Keystone

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/keystone-all --config-file=/etc/keystone/keystone.conf --log-file=/var/log/keystone/keystone.log
```

Which way should I take up in this situation? Reconfigure apache to use a different port, or try to deal with Python to use a different one?

**EDIT**

Referring to https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/47137/devstack-fails-to-start-apache2-address-already-in-use-could-not-bind-to-address/ I modified `/etc/apache2/sites-available/wsgi-keystone.conf` from `<VirtualHost *:5000>` to `<VirtualHost *:80>`, but the error persisted. The message right now is

```
 * Restarting web server apache2
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:35357
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:35357
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Apache error log obviously is empty, so I cannot go there to find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is because Keystone is running using the deprecated Eventlet, thus it is listening on the port `5000`. In order to get it working with Apache, you have to stop and disable the Keystone service before. Keystone won't be executed as a service, as it will be executed as a WSGI application in Apache using `mod_wsgi`.

So, to get things working, roll back your configuration so that you have `<VirtualHost *:5000>` again. Then, stop and disable the `keystone` service and restart Apache:

```
service keystone stop
update-rc.d keystone disable
service apache2 restart
```